# Cannot find Microsoft.Http.dll

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 and have set my project's target framework to .NET Framework 4 but I do not see Microsoft.Http.dll as a reference I can add to my project.

Can someone point me to it's install location on the HDD or to a download somewhere?  I have read that this is supposed to be part of the VS2010 but can't find it.

Comment: What type of application is this? Are you targeting the full .NET Framework, or the Client Profile? This might not be included as part of the Client Profile.

Comment: .Net Framework 4 (not the Client).

Comment: I am creating a WCF Service (API) and want to use this dll in the client test app.

Comment: Can you believe this: http://support.microsoft.com/dllhelp  Way to go, MS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find these DLLs by downloading the REST Starter Kit found [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644).  I extracted the project and then plucked the DLLs out and saved to my computer.  Unfortunately, I cannot say if these are up to date or not.

Never did find out though why these DLLs are not part of VS2010 Ultimate like MS says.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the best way to resolve your problem. Solution to old post but you want to approach this correctly

Use

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http

in your package manager console - make sure it's targeting the correct project in VS